# (Oracle jpql) having count multiple values

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return the rows from Table1 where its id's exists in Table2 1 or 3 times.  This sql works for performing a having count once, but when I include it more than once separated by ORs it fails.

```
    Table1             Table2

id      color            id
-----   -----           -----
1        bl               1
2        r                4
3        g                1
4        y                2
                          1
                          2

SELECT d FROM Table1 d
WHERE d.id IN 
(  SELECT e.id FROM Table2 e
   GROUP BY e.id
   HAVING COUNT(e.id) = 1 OR HAVING COUNT(e.id) = 3
)
```

Expected output:

```
id      color
---      ----- 
1        bl
4        y
```

Comment: All SQL questions need to indicate *which* RDBMS you're using, as they all have drastically different implementations of the SQL language (often violating the standard, even).

Comment: Have you tried omitting the 2nd `HAVING` or using `IN`?

Comment: I omitted the 2nd HAVING keyword and it works, thanks.

Comment: `HAVING` works just like `WHERE` except on groups instead of rows, so just as a SQL statement can have only one `WHERE` clause, it can have only one `HAVING`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT d.* FROM 
Table1 d,
(  SELECT e.id id, COUNT(1) myCount FROM Table2 e
   GROUP BY e.id
) t
WHERE d.id = t.id
AND (t.myCount = 1 OR t.myCount = 3)
```